# How to display the method contents in PHP?

Tags: php

```
$string = "my_method";
$a=explode("_",$string);
foreach($a as $string)
{
    $method=$method.ucwords($string);
}
echo  $method."()";
function MyMethod(){
    return "in my method";
}
```

I got the code 'my_method' from which i have to create the 'MyMethod()' method and display the contents of the method

Comment: `$method = ''; foreach($a as $string) { $method .= $method.ucwords($string); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
<?php

$string = "my_method";
$a = explode("_", $string);
$method = '';

foreach($a as $string)
{
    $method.= ucwords($string);
}

echo $method();

function MyMethod(){
    return "in my method";
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works for my assignment thank you very much actually i had problem with this( echo $method."()"; ) due to the inverted commas it doesn't works

Comment: @ganesh glad it helped. you can accept the answer now ;-)

Comment: m sorry but you said accept.I don't know how to.I am new on stack.. please tell me..

Comment: there must be a tick near my answer score, here in the upper left corner of this box. you click the tick and it becomes green and... that's it :)